# Can I have 2-layer design with PCIe connector?

Tags: pcb, connector, pcie, multi-layer

I was wondering whether I can have a 2-layer instead of 4-layer pcb design with PCIe golden finger and PCIe connector. Should it always be 4-layer, which I found from the PCI-SIG presentation in 2004?

I have tried a 2-layer design before. But had difficulty when routing the gnd signals around the PCIe golden pins as shown below, gnd_a signals(ground signal) interleaves with Tx and Rx signals.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It would be ill-advised. The ground plane availability is key to eliminating cross-talk, and decreasing trace density at the connector - you just drop a via for the ground and route the differential pair in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCIe needs to be referenced to ground to get a single-ended impedance of 60 ohms, in addition to the 100 ohm differential impedance. This would be very hard - if not impossible - to achieve using 2 layer rules and reasonable trace sizes with the .063” thickness PCIe boards have to have.

Further, if there are islands of ground between pairs in an attempt to provide an edge-coupled reference, these islands will be shared with adjacent pairs, leading to crosstalk issues.

If you were only doing 1 lane - might be possible. More lanes?  Don’t think so.